# Where can I associate the magnet protocol in Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, protocol, magnet

I am not able to associate magnet protocol in FF. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with FF 10.0.2. Created the following in about:config and restarted FF, but still getting the below message.

```
Boolean
Name: network.protocol-handler.external.magnet -> Value -> true

String
Name: network.protocol-handler.app.magnet -> Value -> /usr/bin/transmission-gtk
```

[image]

Chrome was able to recognize the magnet, so was able to get it work.

But, still interested in how to get it work in Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this.
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#Firefox_3.5_and_above:

> 1. Type about:config into the Location Bar (address bar) and press Enter.
> 2. Right-click -> New -> Boolean -> Name: network.protocol-handler.expose.foo -> Value -> false (Replace foo with the protocol you're specifying)
> 3. Next time you click a link of protocol-type foo you will be asked which application to open it with.
> 4. Once it works, don't forget to reset the value of 'network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet' to True, or FF might keep asking to setup it again.